# Bootstrap carousel no reacting when responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel set up with a small box inside it to display some text that the user can fill out. This box can be toggled on and off where it slides up and down as required.

However, in mobile devices, this box no longer appears. I've checked the element and I can see that it is firing, but nothing is appearing in my browser. Could someone take a fresh look over my code to see if I forgetting something?

I won't post the whole carousel code, just the affect area.

Carousel affect area:

```
<div class="container-fluid slider np">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <div id="carousel-733617" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    @foreach (var slide in Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<ArchetypeModel>("carousel"))
                    {
                        var imageMedia = Umbraco.Media(slide.GetValue("slideImage")).GetCropUrl("CarouselSlide");
                        var slideHeading = slide.GetValue("heading");
                        var slideText = slide.GetValue("text");
                        string relatedLinksRaw = slide.GetValue("relatedLink");
                        dynamic relatedLinks = null;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(relatedLinksRaw))
                        {
                            relatedLinks = Json.Decode(relatedLinksRaw);
                        }

                        if (slideCount == 0)
                        {
                            slideClass = "item active";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            slideClass = "item";
                        }

                        <div class="@slideClass" @*role="option" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"*@>
                            <img alt="" src="@imageMedia" />
                            <div class="carousel-caption" style="z-index:20;">
                                <div class="buttonslide">
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default pull-right openclose">
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> Close</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="slidecontent">
                                    <h2>@slideHeading</h2>
                                    <p>
                                        @slideText
                                        <br />

                                        @if (relatedLinks != null)
                                        {
                                            foreach (var relatedLink in relatedLinks)
                                            {                                                    
                                                if (relatedLink.newWindow == true)
                                                {                                                       
                                                    <a href="@relatedLink.link" class="btn btn-square" target="_blank">@relatedLink.caption</a>
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <a href="@relatedLink.link" class="btn btn-square">@relatedLink.caption</a>
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                                        slideCount++;
                    }
```

My Javascript that controls the box opening and closing:

```
    $('.openclose').click(function(e) { 
    if ($('.slidecontent').is(":visible")){
        $('.openclose').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> Show More');
    }
    else{
        $('.openclose').html('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> Close'); 
    }   

    $('.slidecontent').toggle('slow');  
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[image]

Above is a quick MS Paint of the issue.

When I shrink down my browser, the carousel (the black box) resizes as per the responsive design. When it reaches a certain width, the green box automatically toggles off and disappears a bar with a button for Open / Close.

When the carousel is full size, the green box works just fine. It is when the black box is shrunk that the green box no longer appears. When I inspect the element, I can see my code is firing off something, however, the green box is not visible on my screen.

Comment: The code you posted above works for me in mobile devices too. Could the problem come from somewhere else? I think of CSS in this case.

Comment: I think it may be something to do with my javascript. I need some sort of way of telling it what to do when the screen is a certain size and automatically flipping

Comment: You want to use media queries in javascript?

Comment: No idea what that is. Right now what I'm trying do is the following: if the page width is less than X, change the button 'close' to 'show more' automatically. But I'm failing to get that to work without clicking the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can add media queries in javascript too.

You just need to change the `500px` to whatever you want and add the code into the `if` you want to use.

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {

    if (mq.matches) {
        // window width is at least 500px

    }
    else {
        // window width is less than 500px

        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps, you can read more about it [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/).

Comment: Whilst this works, the inner box in my carousel still doesn't appear when I toggle the button. That is issue I'm having.

Comment: Then I'm sure it will be some CSS. Can you provide?

Comment: sorry mate, i can't. I have updated my original post with a quick MS Paint image to help get my issue across better as well.

Comment: I get what your issue is, but given these I can't help, because I assume some of your code is broken in CSS, like giving an absolute position to the green box when the browser width is smaller than X. You have given too little information to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the code in your CSS @media property is playing a role here. Check and confirm.

You can manually define how each screen may look. For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

This will change the screen color if screen size is less than 300.

Comment: Good shout. But its my bad, I should have mentioned that a lot of my content is being pulled from an umbraco back end. The @imageMedia is me calling the image that I have set in the back end.